# How does Google determine Information about a person for Google Search?

Tags: seo, google, google-search

For some queries Google Search will return result with a person's information on a right. It looks a bit differently for different queries but most of the time something like this (https://www.google.com/search?q=huskystarcraft):

[image: H to the usky Husky!]

Assuming Google grabs the information from different parts of the Web, the question is:

**How does one put information about a person on the Web in a way that it ends up on Google's search page in described above fashion?**

Answer (score 2):

Google usually pulls this data from various reputable sources. In the example you have shown the bio details is from **Wikipedia** and the image is from **theverge**.

In case of people, different professions get different kind of profile details, like movie stars get a list of recent movies and a football player gets details about awards and team he plays in.

Each search item is tagged with various keywords. For example : messi with 'best player', 'barcelona fc', 'argentina', 'talent'. These keywords are matched with related personalities and the most relevant ones are put down at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

That's the Knowledge Graph feature [launched last year](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/introducing-knowledge-graph-things-not.html).
In the past, Google's search results were largely a matter of matching keywords. Now, for certain things, it makes an attempt to actually "understand" what you're looking for, and provide answers right on the results page. It's not anything you can really take direct action to make happen.